# Can I detect Tor Browser inside the browser itself, via Javascript I suppose?

Tags: firefox, browser, tor

I'd like to disable some features of a web app I'm building, if the browser is Tor Browser. Can I inside the browser itself (client side, not server side) find out if the browser is Tor Browser?

I would prefer a solution that didn't issue any HTTP requests to match the browser's IP against Tor exit nodes.

Background: In my case, Tor Browser pops up a dialog that asks the user *"Should Tor Browser allow this website to extract HTML5 canvas image data?"*, because, says Tor Browser, canvas image data can be used to uniquely identify a browser.

**Update:** After reading the answers below: Perhaps the best solution in my case, is to keep a list of Tor exit nodes server side (an up-to-date list, refreshed periodically), and when a browser loads the page, I set a variable in a `<script>` tag, if the browser's IP matches such an exit node: `var isProbablyTorBrowser = true`. Then, client side, no additional requests, or complicated logic, is needed.

Comment: Do you want to detect that the browser is the Tor Browser Bundle, or that the user is connected to the Internet over Tor?  They're different things, and depending on why you're asking this, you could want either.

Comment: @Mark I would think that the dialog that Tor Browser shows, is specific to Tor Browser Bundle. So, since I want to avoid the dialog, what I want to detect, is probably Tor Browser Bundle. — However, detecting if the user is connected to the Internet over Tor, would probably be good enough, if there is no way to detect the Tor Browser Bundle.

Comment: That dialog also shows up on the Tails browser, which isn't quite the same thing, and it may show up on other anonymity-focused browsers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Tor browser is not designed to be undetectable (that's impossible to do).  Rather, it is designed so that all copies are indistinguishable from each other: you cannot track a browser from one site to another, or from one visit to another, strictly through [browser fingerprinting](https://panopticlick.eff.org/).

This gives it a distinct fingerprint of its own.  As of right now, a browser that

1. Has a User-Agent of `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0`
2. Has a screen resolution that matches the browser window size (particularly if that size is 1000x800)
3. Has a time zone of "0" (GMT)
4. Has no plugins (`navigator.plugins` is empty)

is probably the TBB browser.  The User-Agent string may change when the next ESR version of Firefox comes out, most likely to `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0`.

The screen resolution/browser window match alone may uniquely identify TBB: even in fullscreen mode, there's a one-pixel difference between window height and screen height in Firefox.

Comment: Thanks for the details about how to detect Tor Browser. I think the detection procedure seems a bit fragile, for example, the ever changing User Agent string — in my case, it's probably better to detect Tor server side (compare browser IP with exit node IPs) and set a Javascript variable if there's a match.

Comment: `navigator.plugins` doesn't work because it's empty in Android Firefox 86 too

Comment: @Finesse, the fingerprint changes over time.  The screen resolution/browser window match is probably the most stable aspect.

Answer (score 6):

The "official" way to detect tor is to check the user's IP address and see if it's a tor exit node. Tor runs [TorDNSEL](https://www.torproject.org/projects/tordnsel.html.en) for this purpose.

Here's a PHP implementation of a TorDNSEL lookup from a tutorial by [Irongeek](http://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=security/detect-tor-exit-node-in-php)

```
function IsTorExitPoint(){
    if (gethostbyname(ReverseIPOctets($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']).".".$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'].".".ReverseIPOctets($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']).".ip-port.exitlist.torproject.org")=="127.0.0.2") {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    } 
}

function ReverseIPOctets($inputip){
    $ipoc = explode(".",$inputip);
    return $ipoc[3].".".$ipoc[2].".".$ipoc[1].".".$ipoc[0];
}
```

If you're not using PHP, you should still be able to adapt this relatively easily.

***Another method of detecting Tor is to have a script download the list of Tor exit nodes every half hour or so, then check each user's IP address against that list. This may be less reliable, though, as not all exit nodes are published. There's a list you can use, and instructions, available at [dan.me.uk](https://www.dan.me.uk/tornodes).***

EDIT: Since you updated your question, the second option (a list you host locally) is going to be preferable.

Comment: The set of Tor exit nodes changes too fast for a static list to be useful.  Yes, the major exits are reasonably constant, but smaller ones come and go on a timescale of hours to days.

Comment: @Mark I did provide a solution to that problem in my answer. "have a script download the list of Tor exit nodes every half hour or so"

Comment: Is there any solution for this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48424391/how-to-detect-user-using-the-tor-broswer-using-private-load-balancer-ips-of-aws

Answer (score 5):

There might be a quite reliable way. Check if it returns you a blank (white) image when you try to Base64 it using canvas.
[When you do so an notification is shown.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMYJ9.png)

No matter what user chooses JS returns a white image. So you can try to base64 (<-- it's a verb ;)) a non white image and then check if a white base64 image returned.

UPD.
Here is an example I made for myself. For me it was important to detect if I have an access to the image, but it can be used for Tor detecting in some way.

UPD2.
There even might be no notification shown as it's shown in code snippet below. Maybe because it's ran in an iframe.

```js
function isTorBrowser() {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    // Creates a black 1x1 px image
    img.src = 'data:image/png;base64,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';

    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = 1;
    canvas.height = 1;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var imagedata = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    
    return imagedata.data[0] == 255 
                && imagedata.data[1] == 255
                && imagedata.data[2] == 255
                && imagedata.data[3] == 255;
}

document.getElementById('tor-browser-test').innerHTML = isTorBrowser() ? 'Is Tor' : 'Not Tor';
```

```html
<div id="tor-browser-test"></div>
```

Comment: Hmm if the user says "Allow" in the dialog, then a real (not only white) image will be returned? Then seems to me this approach won't work? — A dialog is a bit intrusive I think, actually too intrusive in my case.

Comment: Thanks anyway for the suggestion / answer :- )

Comment: You are welcome)
And yes, if user says "Allow" then an original image will be returned. But only next time. At first attempt on this domain an blank (white) image is returned.

Comment: This won't produce false negatives (if it says "Not Tor", you know it isn't the Tor browser), but it can produce false positives.  The Tor browser isn't the only thing that has an anti-Canvas-fingerprinting mechanism.

Answer (score 3):

There is no reliable way to detect the TOR Browser... That's kind of a goal of that browser. If you find a reliable way, chances are somebody else finds it too, tells the TOR developers and they close it.

E.g. all TOR Browser bundles report bogus, but reasonable User-Agents. The current release version e.g. says it is `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0` no matter what OS you're actually using.

You may apply some heuristics to detect a TOR Browser with a certain probability, but will also generate some false-positives...

- Check the user agent. TOR Browser will report the latest Firefox ESR on a certain OS, currently Windows 7 32-bit (but some users might have changed that again and other users might simply use the ESR release but not the TOR Browser)
- Plugins are disabled, so `navigator.plugins` will be empty (but some users might have re-enabled plugins again).
- etc.
- Detect the browser actually [uses the TOR network](https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq-abuse.html.en#Bans).

Of course, you'll have to keep your checks up to date, so it requires a fair amount of maintenance busywork.

Personally, given the less than stellar detection results, maintenance burden and very modest experience improvements for users, I wouldn't try to handle TOR Browser differently at all.

Comment: Making Tor browsers indistinguishable is a goal I suppose, but I would think that making them undetectable is not a goal of the Tor project — it seems fairly easy to match a browser's IP against Tor endpoints for example, perhaps in combination with checking your list of features.

Comment: I agree with you that trying to detect Tor client side seems too complicated. What I could do, instead, is to detect it server side (compare browser IP with exit node IPs) and set a Javascript variable to true if there's a match.

Answer (score 0):

By the firefox resource bundle you can check it.

The resource:// URI scheme is used by Firefox to call on-disk resources from internal modules and extensions.

But some of these resources may also be included to any web page and executed via script tag. Mozilla developers is not consider the resources as a fingerprinting vector, despite the fact that some of them can reveal what the user does not wish. For example, differences in built-in preferences files clearly indicates you are using Windows or Linux or Mac, even if you're behind Tor Browser.

https://www.browserleaks.com/firefox