# Detect my website run on tor browser

Tags: javascript, php, browser, tor

I want to run my web page only on tor browser. 
I have searched many scripts but can't detect tor browser. 
So please suggest me that how to detect tor browser in php Or JS script.

Comment: This might help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28200567/can-i-detect-tor-browser-inside-the-browser-itself-via-javascript-i-suppose

Comment: Instead of trying to detect a Tor browser, it's much easier to simply only create a .onion domain towards your server. These pseudo domain names can only be visited with a Tor browser.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I detect Tor Browser inside the browser itself, via Javascript I suppose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28200567/can-i-detect-tor-browser-inside-the-browser-itself-via-javascript-i-suppose)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because after reading the comments it's reasonably clear OP wants us to help him setup a server on Tor which is clearly out of the scope of SO.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have your site hidden you can try and use the .onion extension to have your site exclusively hosted on the Tor network. https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-hidden-service.html.en for more info

Comment: I know you don't have the reputation to add comments yet, but this is not an answer to the question. The question is how to detect Tor browsers. You're not answering that. Instead you're giving a tip into a different direction. So it should be a comment

Comment: @RakeshSharma Follow the link in the answer. It's all clearly explained there.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood the question