# How to detect user using the TOR broswer using private/load balancer ips of AWS

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, tor

I have used the below code from link to detect the browser is TOR or not.

[Code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28201039/2929240)

But when the server is hosted on AWS, we didn't get the exact **$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']** as the AWS is providing the private ip of machine or load balancer ips.

So is there any way to detect the AWS private ips from the TOR exit list to detect whether the user is using the TOR browser or not.

Answer (score 2):

First to make that code work properly, you have to get the actual client IP. That data in sent to your client via the `x-forwarded-for` header:

From [HTTP Headers and Classic Load Balancers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/x-forwarded-headers.html#x-forwarded-for):

> The X-Forwarded-For request header helps you identify the IP address
>   of a client when you use an HTTP or HTTPS load balancer. Because load
>   balancers intercept traffic between clients and servers, your server
>   access logs contain only the IP address of the load balancer. To see
>   the IP address of the client, use the X-Forwarded-For request header.
>   Elastic Load Balancing stores the IP address of the client in the
>   X-Forwarded-For request header and passes the header to your server.

For more information on how to detect Tor exit nodes, see [Tor DNS Exit List](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TorDNSExitList):

> It is useful for a variety of reasons to determine if a connection is
>   coming from a Tor node. Early attempts to determine if a given IP
>   address was a Tor exit used the directory to match IP addresses and
>   exit policies. This approach had a number of drawbacks, including
>   false negatives when a Tor router exits traffic from a different IP
>   address than its OR port listens on. The ​Tor DNS-based Exit List was
>   designed to overcome these problems and provide a simple interface for
>   answering the question: is this a Tor exit?

Comment: I am able to detect whether the user is browser is TOR or not using the same HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR instead of REMOTE_ADDR. But I need the public IP of the server for checking TOR or not also in PHP code. On AWS they provide only private or load balancer IPs.What is the solution for that?

Comment: In this code, gethostbyname($user_ip.".".$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'].".".$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'].".ip-port.exitlist.torproject.org")=="127.0.0.2" , I did the $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] to static public ip of AWS server and $user_ip to $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR '] and code worked, but if I put actual private IP in the $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] variable provided by AWS, code is not working.